# VS Code - How to enable Html tag attribute display

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, attributes

I am new to VS Code and using it for Html editing.  Is there a way to have the IDE show me a list of the attributes available for an Html tag?  I do get Intellisense when I am typing a tag name and it will auto-close the tag, but there doesn't seem to be support for displaying the attributes specific to the tag.  I can use Ctrl-Space to display a universe of attributes, but I'm looking for a list of the attributes from the official Html reference. Or maybe a tag-level help pane where it would display the tag information, including purpose, usage, attributes, etc.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html
 Use extensions but do not overdo it.

Comment: Thanks - I had reviewed the Intellisense reference previously.  I believe the Ctrl-space feature is showing me all attributes but they are not organized by function.  What I was hoping to find would include the popover help or description for each attribute, similar to that displayed when you hover over a tag name. Or maybe context-sensitive help at the tag / attribute level.  I guess I am asking too much of a generic editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without installing an extension, I am getting a list of attributes when I press `Ctrl`+`Space` while inside an open tag like this `<p`.

There must be a space after the `<p`, so the tag name must be complete and the cursor separated from it by a space. If the cursor is still on the tag name, VSCode tries to autocomplete the tag name when pressing `Ctrl`+`Space`.

Comment: You're right - Ctrl + Space seems to be the answer.  There doesn't appear to be additional help for what each attribute does, or what the acceptable values are.  The solution seems to be keeping a browser open to a site having reference information.  Was just hoping someone made an extension for this for use within the VS Code IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In VS Code it is showing attributes available in an HTML tag but it fails when showing/suggesting values for a specific tag. For that purpose, I am using this extension called "HTML CSS Support" by ecmel. But for the scenario mentioned in this question, You can get it done with @C14L 's answer. There may be other good extensions but this is the one I have tried and it works perfectly.

[image]